# Ignoring point in trendline

Tags: google-visualization, google-chat

Is there a way to ignore specific points in a series when drawing a trendline?
In a series, I have some "abnormal" points that I still want to plot but they should be excluded when drawing a trendline.

Comment: you could load a second series with the points removed, draw the series with `color: 'transparent'` and `visibleInLegend: false`, and use this series for the trendline.

Comment: Can you share a sample? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: @WhiteHat thanks for the suggestion. I am keeping that as plan B.